# Is flock() reliable on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, web, operating-system

I'm looking for a way to lock a file so no more than one request can read, write or delete it at a time. I hear `flock()` is meant for that. However I'm running on Linux, and I've read that `flock()` is 'advisory' on Linux.

So my question to you: can I count on `flock()` to reliably lock my files with PHP running over Apache on Linux? Or should I look for a different approach?

Comment: This is something that you could easily test.

Comment: I don't believe it is easy to test at all. If flock() were unreliable only if x number of processes hit the file at the exactly the same time, it would be quite difficult to both make that happen and catch the error that occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advisory means that processes can ignore the `flock` if they want to.  If you are in control of the file and consistently use `flock`, you are fine.  If the file can be manipulated by other processes, then you may have a problem.

Comment: I just want to prevent PHP scripts responding to parallel requests to try and read or write to a file while a different PHP script is doing so. For this use case, should flock be reliable?

Comment: As long as all scripts consistently use flock, it can be relied upon.